# For arbitrary positive integral $n,$ find the sum $2^{n}+2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}+\ldots+2^{-n+1}+2^{-n}$

Tags: summation

> For arbitrary positive integral $n,$ find the sum $$2^{n}+2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}+\ldots+2^{-n+1}+2^{-n}.$$

My solution:
$$\begin{align}
2^{n}+2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}+\ldots+2^{-n+1}+2^{-n}&=2^{n}[2^{0}+2^{-1}+2^{-2}+2^{-3}+\dots 2^{-n}]\\
&=2^{n}\sum_{0}^{n}2^{-n}\\
&=2^{n}[2-\frac{1}{2^{2n}}]\\
&=2^{n+1}-2^{-n}.
\end{align}$$
Is my solution correct?

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: If what I have done is correct , which from @robert Z's correction it isn't

Comment: so I'm trying to see if I can make sense of his suggestion

Comment: if you plug in 1 for n (or any other number) you can see that your first equation is wrong. In the 3rd expression the  symbol $\sum_{0}^{n}$ does not make sense. There is a variable missing, something like $\sum_{i=0}^{n}$ is necessary.

Comment: thanks, I get it now from the explanation below